# IE background image repeat

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a weird issue trying to get my site logo to display properly across all browsers. My current code works perfectly for chrome, firefox, and safari, but the no-repeat isn't working in ie8.

**application layout**:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    /[if lt IE 9]
      = stylesheet_link_tag 'ie8/ie8'
  %body
    %header
      %ul.navbar
        %li
          = link_to 'Logo', root_url, id: 'logo'
```

**header.sass**:

```
#logo
  background-size: 100% Auto
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-image: url(logo.png)
```

**ie8.css**:

```
#logo {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='logo.png',
    sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

I'm able to solve the ie8 image repeat problem by changing my header.sass file to:

```
#logo
  background: 'logo.png' no-repeat 100% Auto
```

Fixing the sass file to account for ie8 breaks all the other browsers, though; the image is no longer the right size. Is there any way I can reconcile the two? I'd like to get the ie8 browsers working if at all possible, but not at the expense of the other browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure you can include background-size in background. Without doing much research to back myself up, it looks like the 100% would correlate to the background-position.

Comment: When I took the `100% Auto` out, the logo was just gone in chrome/safari/firefox. It didn't make a difference to ie. If I left the background-size property in and had `background: 'logo.png' no-repeat`, none of the browsers worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 requires a `<!DOCTYPE html>` 
in the beggining of your html document in order for a no repeat function to work...

In your case however, you would need to do  `!!!html`

so your code would be

```
!!!html

    %html
      %head
        = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
        = javascript_include_tag 'application'
        /[if lt IE 9]
          = stylesheet_link_tag 'ie8/ie8'
      %body
        %header
          %ul.navbar
            %li
              = link_to 'Logo', root_url, id: 'logo'
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I have that in my html, I just forgot to put it in my question. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need the hashrocket for the id

```
= link_to 'Logo', root_url, :id => 'logo'
```